# How to untar all .tgz files in a folder and write to new files with different Naming convention

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I have folder thay contains many **.tgz** files, each uncompressed file has **SAME** file name "**000000_0**".

Can someone write me a command to do below?

```
1. Untar all the .tgz files from a folder
2. rename each uncompressed file based on the .tgz file name
```

For example,  **2017-07-01.tgz**  ->  I want the uncompressed file to be renamed as "**2017-07-01.dat**"

Suppose I have list of .tgz file in a directory:

```
2017-07-01.tgz
2017-07-02.tgz
2017-07-03.tgz
2017-07-04.tgz
2017-07-05.tgz
```

Note: each .tgz file only have one file inside, "**000000_0**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gnu parallel`:

```
$ parallel 'tar -xf {} --to-stdout > {.}.dat' ::: *.tgz
```

For each `.tgz` file the file is uncompressed (`-xf`) and the content of the file streamed stdout (`--to-stdout`). So we can redirect (`>`) it to a file with a new filename, using the basename of the compressed file (`{.}.dat`)

Without `gnu parallel`:

```
for file in *.tgz; do 
tar -xf $file --to-stdout > $(basename -s .tgz $file).dat;
done
```

If the `basename` version is to old, the `-s` parameter doesn't exist. Use `$(basename $file .tgz)` instead. This should work in current versions as well.

Comment: i don't have the privilege to install GNU parallel utility, is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: See my edit please.

Comment: I got this error: basename: invalid option -- s

Comment: basename --version
basename (GNU coreutils) 5.97

Comment: Wow, this version is from the stone age ;) Edit my post again.

Comment: thank you so much! that actually works by using "$(basename $file .tgz)".  I will test more files..

Comment: @azCats "I don't have the privilege..." Can you elaborate if you have read https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/